# What is this python script doing?

Tags: bittorrent, deluge, schedule

What I need is an executable file (so that I can double click and open) of Deluge Bit torrent client. I found this, **deluge.py** is my **usr/bin** folder.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'deluge==1.3.5','gui_scripts','deluge'
__requires__ = 'deluge==1.3.5'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('deluge==1.3.5', 'gui_scripts', 'deluge')())
```

I need such a  file or command to enter in "task schedule" program to open it on a schedule. So will this script serve the purpose. Can I use some other method?

Comment: Please be more descriptive about what you are trying to achieve with Deluge as there is a daemon that might be more suited to your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is a write-up about gnome Task Scheduler http://www.ubuntugeek.com/tag/ubuntu-task-scheduler

> Gnome-schedule is a graphical user interface that leverages the power
> of vixie-cron, dcron and at to manage your crontab file and provide an
> easy way to schedule tasks on your computer. It supports recurrent
> (periodical) tasks and tasks that happen only once in the future. It
> is written in Python using pygtk, and has been developed, tested and
> packaged for various Linux distributions.
>
> #### Awesome features
>
> - Supports custom titles and icons for your tasks so that they are more easily to keep track of.
> - Templates support so that you won't have to create the same task again and again; these are saved in gconf and may easily ship them
>   with, say, a Linux distribution.
> - If run as root, you can edit any user's crontab and "at" tasks.
> - Human-readable strings like "Every hour" instead of "0 * * * *"
> - Advanced mode for crontab experts
> - Provides a "panel applet" where you can manage tasks from a dropdown menu.
> - Predefined common expressions like: every minute, every week, tomorrow, next week
> - A calendar allows you to choose the day you want a task executed
>
> Install gnome-schedule in Ubuntu
>
> Open the terminal and run the following command
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule
> ```